# How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

I have used `brew install openssl` to download and install openssl v1.0.2f, however, it comes back saying:

```
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

And when I do `openssl version -a` it always gives me:

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
built on: Jul 31 2015
platform: darwin64-x86_64-llvm
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O3 -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_NO_IDEA -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
OPENSSLDIR: "/System/Library/OpenSSL"
```

How can I replace the old version with the new one? I've searched a lot on how to do this, but the solutions online don't seem to work for me...

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @ksl Nope! :/ None of the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 64):

Execute following commands:

```
brew update
brew install openssl
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

You will have the latest version of openssl installed and accessible from cli (command line/terminal). Since the third command will add export path to `.bash_profile`, the newly installed version of openssl will be accessible across system restarts.

Comment: When I run `$ openssl version` I get `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016` but when I run `$ brew install openssl` I get `Warning: openssl 1.0.2l is already installed`. Does this mean I have two versions installed?

Comment: I guess, you have 2 versions  of openssl in your system now. One available by default with mac and the other one you installed using brew. Execute the third and fourth commands above to access the latest version(1.0.2l) of openssl from the command line.

Comment: The key is to use `/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl` instead of your `/usr/bin/openssl`.

Answer (score 34):

Only

```
export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)/bin:$PATH in ~/.bash_profile
```

has worked for me!
Thank you mipadi.

Comment: I found util for people who like me have tried everything they read about how to link the last openssl.

Comment: this has also been the only thing that has worked for me on osX Sierra, WITHOUT disabling SIP. Thanks!

Comment: THis will severely slow down your terminal.

Answer (score 11):

*I can't reproduce your issue running El Cap + Homebrew 1.0.x*

Upgrade to Homebrew 1.0.x, which was released late in September 2016. [Specific changes were made in the way openssl is linked](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/612). The project is on a more robust release schedule now that it's hit 1.0.

```
brew uninstall openssl
```

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup && brew doctor
```

You should fix any issues raised by `brew doctor` before proceeding.

```
brew install openssl
```

***Note:*** *Upgrading homebrew will update all your installed packages to their latest versions.*

Comment: No, don't do this. It will upgrade everything.

Comment: Added disclaimer about updating. As time goes on, upgrading homebrew to version 1.x will become more and more necessary. The issue has been resolved in homebrew 1.x as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks. On version 1.x, `brew upgrade` does not upgrade everything?

Comment: @BSeven maybe it's necessary to overcome other lib problems?

Answer (score 9):

Try creating a symlink, make sure you have openssl installed in `/usr/local/include` first.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/{version}/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl
```

More info at [Openssl with El Capitan](https://medium.com/@zlwaterfield/openssl-with-el-capitan-456bf68bf43a).

Comment: Your link no longer exists.

Comment: @Hauke Updated!

Comment: this solved my problem, after trying everything else for over an hour, thank you.

Comment: Awesome to hear!

Answer (score 4):

this command solve my problem on github CI job and virtualbox

```sh
brew install openssl@1.1
cp /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig/*.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Answer (score 3):

I reached this page when I searched for information about openssl being keg-only. I believe I have understood the reason why Homebrew is taking this action now. My solution may work for you:

- Use the following command to make the new openssl command available (assuming you have adjusted PATH to put /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin):

  `ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/`
- When compiling with openssl, follow Homebrew's advice and use

  `-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`
- Alternatively, you can make these settings permanent by putting the following lines in your .bash_profile or .bashrc:

  `export CPATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
  export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but still answering it in present-day context as many of the above answers may not work now.

The problem is that the Path is still pointing to the old version. Two solutions can be provided for resolution :

1. Uninstall old version of openssl package `brew uninstall openssl` and then reinstall the new version : `brew install openssl`
2. point the PATH to the new version of openssl.First install the new version and now(or if) you have installed the latest version, point the path to it: `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score -1):

You can run `brew link openssl` to link it into `/usr/local`, if you don't mind the potential problem highlighted in the warning message. Otherwise, you can add the openssl bin directory to your path:

```
export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: No; Homebrew will yell at you if you do this.  Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17016758/17597 for an explanation of keg-only dependencies.  As mentioned in the answer above, you can use `--force` to override, but you should understand the potential consequences of doing so.

Answer (score -1):

To replace the old version with the new one, you need to change the link for it. Type that command to terminal.

```
brew link --force openssl
```

Check the version of openssl again. It should be changed.

Comment: After `brew link`, for me at least, the OpenSSL appears to be updated. But something is not "right". I executed `brew doctor` and there is a warning for *keg-only* formula, this is a substring of all the output: `Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.` And suggests to `brew unlink openssl`. Should be ignored?

Comment: @Knaak This doesn't work on El Capitan with Homebrew 0.9.9. It responds with the message `Warning: Refusing to link: openssl`.