# Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client

Tags: java, apache, ssl, https, openssl

I tried to connect to a server through https protocol,but it gave the error "**Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client**",tried by changing the browser configurations but did not work?
server - apache httpd 2.2.14
openssl - openssl-0.9.8n

Comment: I'm guessing OpenSSL 0.9.8 means OS X. Also see [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), etc.

Comment: I do not fully understand your problem, and you should expand your question to include a specific question you want answered. If you use JDK 7, then TLSv1 is the default, if you use JDK 8, it should be TLSv1.2 thats default instead. All Java versions since v6 support TLSv1, so I fail to see how it is not enabled.