# OpenSSL not getting linked with Homebrew

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, symlink, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to code in C on mac (el capitan) and need to use OPENSSL.
OS ships with `version 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016.`

I used homebrew to upgrade and install openssl (got version 1.0.2h) but am unable to link it correctly to use it. Am facing the same issue as mentioned in this question: [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/brew-refusing-to-link-openssl)

It seems answers to the above question are not valid anymore coz of some update in brew.

My path references `/usr/local/bin` as the first one.

Ran this command: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl`
 (found this solution here: https://medium.com/@zlwaterfield/openssl-with-el-capitan-456bf68bf43a#.f9tkjeo7w among other places)

got no error output, so I assumed this worked. But..

`which openssl` gives me this output: `/usr/local/bin/openssl`

`openssl version` gives me this output: `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`

Any ideas on how to proceed?

@jww am not sure what you mean by "build your stuff". I am not a programmer and hence do not really fully understand vocabulary. Just trying to learn some stuff.

I ran

`brew update`

`brew install openssl`

`brew link --force openssl`

which gave me error saying

`Warning: Refusing to link: openssl`.

I didnt write this for sake of brevity and instead I provided link to question which showed exactly the problem I was facing. Coz earlier I have been told I have not been brief enough in forming que.

Also, the command I am running on CLI which led me to this path was this (if that helps):

`openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ec-priv.pem ex-message.txt >ex-signature.der`.

Gives me an error:

`EVP_SignFinal:wrong public key type`.

Googling led me to understand its coz of an old openssl version which I need to update. Does this answer your question?

Comment: State where the OpenSSL you want to use is located. Show how you configured your project if its Autoconf based. Show your compiler and linker commands. Also see [Brew refusing to link openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Comment: Thanks @jww: have already seen those questions. Where is openssl located: `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j`. No project as such. Just dabbling with plain C code edited with `vi`, compiled using `gcc`, testing using `CLI` commands.

Comment: Thanks @Tuhina. I voted to close because you won't provide the commands you are using to build your stuff. If all you seek is how to put `openssl` on-path, then you should ask on an appropriate site, like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue of linking openssl was resolved like this:
I only had to close the old shell window and running the new shell window to run command `openssl version` and it showed me the correct new version. Basically the explicit linking worked with the command that i stated in the question.

Comment: That was the same case for me. Very odd. I was getting the error `Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1`, but when closing and re-opening the terminal on Mac, `openssl version` gave me the output I was hoping to see of `OpenSSL 1.1.1j`