# OpenSSL has the wrong version installed or is missing from my system

Tags: php, mysql, macos, openssl, homebrew

I Have been trying to solve this issue when I try to execute `composer install` in a new project. I found many solutions including:

```
brew update
brew install openssl force link

export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)/bin:$PATH in ~/.bash_profile
```

but all leads to this error:

> Problem 1
>
> - minishlink/web-push v1.1 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
> - laravel-notification-channels/webpush dev-master requires minishlink/web-push 1.1.* -> satisfiable by minishlink/web-push[v1.1].
> - Installation request for laravel-notification-channels/webpush dev-master -> satisfiable by laravel-notification-channels/webpush[dev-master].

```
$ which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

$ openssl version -a  
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
```

and my PHP version is 5.6.24.

My question is if I uninstall it, I get a warning:

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j
because it is required by mysql, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
```

Will MYSQL be affected if I uninstall OpenSSL and re-install it? Do I have to re-install MySQL and PHP? Because I'm working on some projects and I'm afraid to mess things up.
**UPDATE**

I found the solution in the comment below and it's not mentioned in the website here :) Good luck!
Thank you

Comment: Also see [Brew refusing to link openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/update-openssl-on-os-x-with-homebrew)

Comment: I have tried all ove the above answers but no luck ...