# Upgrade OpenSSL to integrate fastlane (Xcode 8.2.1)

Tags: ios, openssl, homebrew, xcode8, fastlane

I'm integrating fastlane to streamline the app submission process. When I enter `fastlane init` and my apple ID in the terminal, I get an SSL error `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`. I have tried various ways of upgrading OpenSSL including [this post](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-openssl-8d005554401#.eta7xzebq) to no avail. Is there a way to upgrade OpenSSL so I can use fastlane? Thank you.

Comment: Also see [Brew refusing to link openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pre-bundled version of fastlane from [download.fastlane.tools](https://download.fastlane.tools) that bundles the latest OpenSSL version with it. Alternatively you can also use the homebrew version using `brew cask install fastlane`