# Some wrong with curl in mac. About _OpenSSL_version_num Symbol

Tags: macos, curl, https, openssl, homebrew

I want to install brew in my macbook pro. but I get some error while install it by curl(curl not support https),and I install openssl(version 1.1.0e) again. Then, I remake and reinstall the curl(version 7.52.1) project. And now, curl run with this error info.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _OpenSSL_version_num
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
dyld: Symbol not found: _OpenSSL_version_num
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

My question is how to uninstall the curl clear? And how to resolve my problem?

Comment: Also see [Brew refusing to link openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve that by delete all files about openssl and curl under the folder(/usr/local). And it looks like the openssl and curl back to the default of mac.And I can use curl and openssl normally now.