# Can't update to the latest version of openssl on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

Can anyone tell me how to update to the latest openssl? I've tried everything I can on what I have found but just keep getting the warning:

> Warning: Refusing to link: openssl Linking keg-only openssl means you
>   may end up linking against the insecure, deprecated system OpenSSL
>   while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl. Instead, pass the
>   full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
>   -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Thanks

Comment: That warning means you have the lastest SSL, but to link/use it, you need to use the flags it tells you to

Comment: Also see [Brew refusing to link openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.