# Composer won't use latest version of openssl

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, php-openssl

```
➜  ~ composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: WARNING
The OpenSSL library (0.9.8za) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.
```

But this doesn't appear to match the version of OpenSSL I've actually got running.

```
➜  ~ which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
➜  ~ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

I realise there are similar questions but as the most popular answer suggests using the now broken command

```
brew link --force openssl
```

which as per the comments doesn't work.

Comment: `openssl` program isn't the `openssl` library that PHP was built with. Composer has nothing to do with using anything, you need to build your PHP with appropriate version of openssl library.

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.