# Ruby SSL Error, read server "certificate B: certificate verify failed"

Tags: ruby, macos, https, openssl, rvm

I'm attempting to save something to my DB but the default flow requires a successful call to geocode lat/lng before saving, which is when this error is thrown.

The error I get is:

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

I googled it and found what seemed to be a similar issue with [RubyGems](http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue). I followed the instructions to manually change the ssl by downloading a new one and copying it into the ssl_certs directory to no avail.

My environment:

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
RVM 1.29.1
Ruby 2.2.2p95
Rails 4.2.7
```

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Comment: @jww I've tried what most of them recommend, but can't seem to get past attempting to link openssl. Did I miss something?

Comment: Please post the URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: I don't know how you created your certificate, but ***`CN=example.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
gem update --system
```

Also make sure your openssl is linked

```
 brew link openssl
```

Comment: That last command generates the following error:

`Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

Which I can't seem to get past.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue with what I consider to be a bit of a hack, but it may work for you. I just disabled SSL verification in the controller that throws the error with the following line of code:

`OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

From what I can tell, there's an issue with what certs Ruby and RVM use and it differs between versions. Every fix I tried involved downloading new certs and manually placing them in the Ruby or OpenSSL directories but that didn't work. Here are some of the resources I consulted during this adventure:

- [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/ubl6iw/fix-ssl_connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificate-verify-failed-openssl-ssl-sslerror)
- [Toadle.me](https://toadle.me/2015/04/16/fixing-failing-ssl-verification-with-rvm.html)
- [Mislav](http://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/)