# How can I update openssl on Mac OS with homebrew?

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

I've been trying to get .NET Core SDK for VSCode on my MBP. I've went through the steps on the [website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos). However, after restarting multiple times, when I type
 `openssl version`, the output is: `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`.
I typed in `which openssl`, this comes up: `/usr/bin/openssl`. How can I update openssl?

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Comment: As a general remark, [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) doesn't update anything that comes with macOS. It installs alternative (usually newer) versions of many software packages included in macOS and, because it puts links to them in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` usually comes before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`, these alternative versions are found and used instead of the default versions provided by macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that which exist link to openssl actual file(/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/bin/openssl) in Homebrew symbolic-link directory(/usr/local/bin).
I created the link, and add path to my rcfile(~/.zshrc) . Then it works.

'export PATH=$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH'