# How to install Siege with libssl?

Tags: macos, openssl, siege

I am trying to install [Siege](https://github.com/tail/siege) with libssl on Mac OS 10.12, but when I use the utility against an `https` url I am receiving the following error.

> [error] HTTPS requires libssl: Unable to reach https://example.com/
>   with this protocol: Socket is already connected

I am installing with the following commands from this [wiki](https://wiki.mikejung.biz/Siege):

```
./configure --with-ssl
make
make install
```

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is on macOS Mojave, with openssl installed using HomeBrew. You'll be using a `brew` command to get the openssl install directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/JoeDog/siege.git
cd siege

./utils/bootstrap

# here's what you're looking for:
./configure --with-ssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)

make
```

Now you can run siege with `./src/siege https://whatever.domain.invalid`. This was tested with Siege 4.0.4rc3 commit hash 05dcfac88ecdd57bd94276e4ce82477cba9129b6 and openssl 1.0.2s on macOS 10.14.5.

Answer (score 2):

use brew to install siege.
it fixed the issue for me. the only extra thing i had to do was to link siege.

https://coderwall.com/p/qfrk1w/making-siege-work-with-https-on-os-x-mavericks . 
brew uninstall siege
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
brew install siege

The extra steps ti had to do (Mac OS Sierra low) . 
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/siege/4.0.4/bin/siege /usr/local/bin/siege .

Comment: Doesn't semm to work anymore:
`brew link --force openssl`

`Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`