# siege - HTTPS requires libssl - MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, openssl, macos-mojave, siege

I Installed SIEGE 4.0.4

I install from source

I install this too :D :

brew install openssl
brew install zlib

But im getting this error:

[error] HTTPS requires libssl: Unable to reach sitename.tld with this protocol: Socket is already connected

Answer (score 0):

Installing through `brew` worked for me:

```
brew install siege
```

You might also need to set up flags as described:

> If you need to have openssl first in your PATH run:
>
> ```
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:
>
> ```
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
> ```

Note: this was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930929/832136), but I can't mark it as duplicate because it hasn't been accepted.