# openssl / ctls trouble with vapor 2

Tags: ssl, openssl, vapor

How can I fix these OpenSSL / TLS issues I'm getting with Vapor 2? They are preventing me from compiling my project on the command line and in Xcode.

During SPM build:

```
note: you may be able to install ctls using your system-packager:

    brew install ctls

note: you may be able to install ctls using your system-packager:

    brew install openssl
```

Upon failure of SPM build:

```
Linking ./.build/debug/Run
ld: library not found for -lcrypto for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2017-03-07-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/tanner/Desktop/PackageConfig/.build/debug.yaml
```

Also in SPM:

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "shim.h"
        ^
/Users/tanner/Desktop/PackageConfigTwo/.build/checkouts/ctls.git-9210868160426949823/shim.h:4:10: error: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found
#include <openssl/conf.h>
         ^
/Users/tanner/Desktop/PackageConfigTwo/.build/checkouts/crypto.git-7980259129511365902/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher+Method.swift:1:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CTLS'
import CTLS
       ^
```

In Xcode:

```
/Users/tanner/PackageConfig/.build/checkouts/ctls.git-9210868160426949823/shim.h:4:10: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found

/Users/tanner/PackageConfig/.build/checkouts/crypto.git-7980259129511365902/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher+Method.swift:1:8: Could not build Objective-C module 'CTLS'

ld: library not found for -lssl
```

[image: Xcode Failing with CTLS issues]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This error means OpenSSL is either not installed or not being properly linked. There are three solutions to this problem.

## Option 1: Use Vapor Toolbox (Recommended)

Install the latest version of the Vapor toolbox.

If you have already installed the toolbox, try uninstalling it first:

```
which vapor
rm -rf /path/to/vapor
```

### 1.1 Install (macOS)

Add Vapor's Homebrew Tap

```
brew tap vapor/homebrew-tap
```

Update Homebrew and install the toolbox.

```
brew update
brew install vapor
```

### 1.2 Install (Ubuntu)

Add Vapor's APT repo.

#### Quick Script

```
eval "$(curl -sL https://apt.vapor.sh)"
```

#### Manual

```
wget -q https://repo.vapor.codes/apt/keyring.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://repo.vapor.codes/apt $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vapor.list
```

#### Install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vapor
```

### 1.3 Done

You should now have access to the `vapor` program and all required dependencies should be installed.

```
vapor build
vapor xcode
```

`swift build` and related commands should now also work normally.

```
swift build
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

## Option 2: Install Vapor's CTLS Package

### 2.1 Install (macOS)

Add Vapor's Homebrew Tap

```
brew tap vapor/homebrew-tap
```

Update Homebrew and install CTLS

```
brew update
brew install ctls
```

Restart your terminal, re-generate your Xcode project (if using Xcode), and try again.

### 2.2 Install (Ubuntu)

Add Vapor's APT repo.

#### Quick Script

```
eval "$(curl -sL https://apt.vapor.sh)"
```

#### Manual

```
wget -q https://repo.vapor.codes/apt/keyring.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://repo.vapor.codes/apt $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vapor.list
```

Update APT and install CTLS.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ctls
```

### 2.3 Done

`swift build` and other commands should now work normally.

## Option 3: Manually Install and Link OpenSSL or Equivalent

### 3.1 Install (macOS)

Install OpenSSL (or any other similar SSL library)

```
brew install openssl
brew install libressl
```

### 3.2 Install (Ubuntu)

Install OpenSSL (or any other similar SSL library)

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

### 3.3 Finding Linker Flags

You can use `pkg-config` (available on brew and apt) to find linker flags or most packages.

```
pkg-config <package-name> --cflags
pkg-config <package-name> --libs
```

However, OpenSSL installed through Homebrew [cannot be linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl) and thus does not work with `pkg-config`. These flags should work:

```
include: /usr/local/opt/openssl/include
libs: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

Note, some libraries will be installed into `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` which does not require explicit linker flags. OpenSSL through APT is installed this way.

### 3.4 Using Linker Flags

Linker flags can be added during `swift build`

```
swift build -Xswiftc -I/path/to/include -Xlinker -L/path/to/lib
```

They can also be added during Xcode project generation.

```
swift package -Xswiftc -I/path/to/include -Xlinker -L/path/to/lib generate-xcodeproj
```

Comment: Since you brought HomeBrew into it... Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 0):

@tanner0101 your suggestions here https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/937 have not resolved the issue for me. I get the CTLS is missing error not only on High Sierra but also on Ubuntu inside a Docker container.

The project is manually executable but MySQL does not work. I think that this https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/954 and this https://github.com/uchicago-cloud/mpcs51033-2017-spring-forum/issues/54 are not just deployment on Heroku issues.