# Couldn't link OpenSSL

Tags: .net, openssl, homebrew, .net-core

I'm using the OS X Sierra with the latest version of Homebrew. I'm trying to install *openssl* to get started using *dotnet*. But even though I tried to uninstall *openssl* and unlink its directory, but it still doesn't work. 
I think the root problem I haven't been able to fix it here is that I could link the place where *openssl* is already installed to the directory of `/usr/local/opt/openssl`

```
brew link --force openssl

Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`
```

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are using very old instructions for .NET Core on macOS. Try https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```