# Curl error: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54

Tags: php, macos, curl, openssl

I keep getting this error, i am running OS X, PHP71, Apache 2.4, OpenSSL

php -i | grep "SSL Version" returns SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2k

PHP and CURL have been installed like this:

```
$ brew install --with-openssl curl

$ brew install --with-homebrew-curl --with-httpd24 php71
```

Comment: Error 54 means unable to connect. It could be an issue with the certificate of the source. Where are you trying to connect? What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. In case someone else runs into this, I got it working with:

> vagrant box add laravel/homestead -c --insecure

Options used:

**-c** or **--clean** Clean any temporary download files

**--insecure** Do not validate SSL certificates

Or maybe you need turn on ur VPN.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it worked after a few retries whereby the download progress resumed each time.

Just a guess - but it could be due to unstable wifi and the download process being particularly adverse to it.

I live in a brick building which is built with bricks containing lead... it is rough ok...

Answer (score 0):

if it happens in time of installing homestead laravel 
then The following command resolved my issue:

vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

instead of only: vagrant box add laravel/homestead

Thanks 
Aman ullah