# openssl command not found in osx El Capitan

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, homebrew

I'm trying to update OpenSSL following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-upgrade-openssl-8d005554401)

I run:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

When I check

```
ls -l /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

I get:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Filipe  admin  24 Apr 29 12:48 /usr/local/opt/openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k
```

But when I run:

```
openssl version -a
```

I get:

> -bash: openssl: command not found

I already restarted Terminal, but no changes.

Comment: I don't think System Integrity Protection will let you put your symbolic link in `/usr/bin/` unless you have disabled it.

Comment: I have disabled System Integrity @AlexanderO'Mara

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with your symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

Should be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

You have the incorrect version specified (`j` instead of `k`).