# Fatal Error: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, homebrew

I'm using a compiler to try to make a set of files I've been given and the line #include  breaks with the error: Fatal Error: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found.

I've already installed openssl using brew, but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to somehow connect openssl with my folder that I'm working in?

I'm on the newest mac OS sierra.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  What's its search path for include files?  Does it include the Homebrew OpenSSL directory?

Comment: How would I change the path to include Howbrew and OpenSSL?

Comment: I don't know.  You haven't told us what compiler or build system you're using.

Comment: I'm using a CC compiler in a makefile

Comment: "CC" *means* "C compiler".  Do you mean `/usr/bin/cc`, i.e., Clang?

Comment: Yeah that's the one

Comment: State where the OpenSSL you want to use is located. Show how you configured your project if its Autoconf based. Show your compiler and linker commands. Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running:

```
brew info openssl
```

gives the solution :

```
For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: How does this work in xcode? I have added `-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` to `Other Linker Flags` and `-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` to `Other C Flags` but xcode won't find openssl/conf.h

Comment: @78573 It's better to ask a new question with all details.

Comment: I have made a mistake, my lib was outdated and did not match dependencies, that's why it did not work in my scenario. An update helped.