# Unable to install HomeBrew on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, openssl, homebrew

I just really need to install Sass. But then it led to this error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

my ruby version is :

```
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

my rubygem version is:

```
2.0.14.1
```

while my openssl version is:

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

so I tried researching about the error, and then it led me to this  [link](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html), there was a lot about installing RVM but I couldn't due to curl(60) error - so I checked another probable cause which described a diagnosis that I should upgrade my openssl. So...

1. I tried to install homebrew so that it would let me update openssl, created a .bash_profile with this `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`
2. executed this to terminal `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

and then another error occured:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I already checked my certificates and there are no expired ones.

If there are still any other details you need to know to help me please let me know. I'm really desperate already... I just want to move on and learn SASS. T_T

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Comment: @jww I already tried all of these links. But the main problem was installing Homebrew..

Comment: You could try an updated `cacert.pem`. See cURL's [CA certificates extracted from Mozilla](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). You could also try one of the [Alternative Installs](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Installation.md#installation) for it. `mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew` looks like a good alternative. You can also tell `curl` to ignore certificate errors due to an old `cacerts.pem`.

Comment: @jww I tried the alternative install mkdir... and it said 'mkdir:homebrew: FIle exists' but when I try to brew install... it did a command not found

Comment: You should probably move this question to a site like [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). You seem to be having trouble with basic commands, like `mkdir` and `rm`; and how to use `curl`. There's nothing related to programming or development here.

Comment: @jww all of the links you gave me were from this site. :/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone had this problem.. It's due to proxy. Just use http. Thanks.