# WooCommerce Gateway PayPal Express Checkout requires OpenSSL >= 1.0.1

Tags: wordpress, macos, woocommerce, openssl, homebrew

I am running OSX Sierra 10.12.5 with PHP 5.6.30 and have a local Wordpress / WooCommerce setup with the "woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout" plugin installed. I am seeing an error in the admin relating to my OpenSSL version:

```
WooCommerce Gateway PayPal Express Checkout requires OpenSSL >= 1.0.1 to be installed on your server
```

I also have other issues with cURL request to https pages, as well as the Wordpress update check not working; which I understand to be related.

In my php info, I have this entry for OpenSSL

```
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version LibreSSL 2.2.7
OpenSSL Header Version  LibreSSL 2.2.7
Openssl default config  /private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

From the command line, the version is reported as:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

Lastly, the server environment reported by WooCommerce status is:

```
### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) LibreSSL/2.2.7 PHP/5.6.30
PHP Version: 5.6.30
PHP Post Max Size: 8 MB
PHP Time Limit: 31
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.51.0
SecureTransport
```

I am at a loss as to how to fix this. I understand that the LibreSSL is a branch of OpenSSL, and is more secure. I have searched for a solution, and several seem to suggest running `brew install openssl` and then `brew upgrade openssl`. This doesn't seem to fix the problem. I know there are several similar or related questions, but most of the responses were either a couple of years old, or seemed to cause other problems.

I have several machines with this problem and would really like to get a better understanding for what is going wrong.

Comment: You probably have a path problem. Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.