# Can't use openssl on macOS-Sierra

Tags: macos, cmake, openssl, homebrew, macos-sierra

I want to get openssl running with CLion (CMake) on my Mac.

Installed openssl with homebrew

```
brew install openssl
```

But still CLion is unable to find openssl. In the past it was possible to use

```
brew link openssl
```

but it seems that today this is refused by homebrew.

```
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure, 
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
   -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

Then I used following cmake options in CLion (CMakeLists.txt)

```
set(I "/usr/local/opt/openssl/include")
set(L "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib")
include_directories(${I})
```

But still I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_DigestSignFinal", referenced from:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_DigestSignFinal", referenced from:
      OpenSSL::signMsg(Buffer, Buffer, SignOptions) in libMyLib.a(ssl_state.cpp.o)
      OpenSSL::signMsg(Buffer, Buffer, SignOptions) in libMyLib.a(ssl_state.cpp.o)
```

Nearly everything I could find to this thematic was about older versions of macOS, but Apple has removed development-headers from openssl 0.9.8, so many guides does not work anymore.

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with linking. I'm using **Macports** instead of **Homebrew**, but also on MacOS Sierra.

Since I can't see your code and you didn't provide a minimum working example, I used: https://github.com/Andersbakken/openssl-examples.git

Similar to you, I added the following lines to `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(I "/opt/local/include")
set(L "/opt/local/lib")
include_directories(${I})
```

and it works just fine for me:

```
cmake .
make
```

Have you verified, that the necessary files are actually available under the paths, you put in your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Have you tried:

```
brew info openssl
```