# OpenSSL from console commands to functions

Tags: ios, c, macos, openssl

I'm hobbyst developer that uses iOS/macOS utilities, and I'm struggling with some openssl commands. 
I execute an openssl command in macos termninal

`openssl smime -sign -signer *certificate.cer* -inkey *miPrivateKey* -out *outFile* -in *inFile* -outform PEM -nodetach`

I would like to know the C functions associated with console commands. In particular this one up.
How can I find a reference from terminal commands to the functions that are executed?
Is there a way to know which functions are being called.
I have successfully loaded all the libraries and call methods but I don't know how to make this one up or which functions to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm hobbyst developer that uses iOS/macOS utilities ...

Apple distributes an ancient version of OpenSSL. Its version 0.9.8. It End-of-Life, and its missing lots og goodies like TLS 1.2, Sever Name Indication, most Elliptic Curve gear, etc.

Usually, you use Homebrew or Macports to install a newer version. For that, see:

- [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661/608639)
- [How to install latest version of openssl OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977/608639)
- [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830/608639)
- [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389/608639)
- [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295/608639)
- etc

---

> I execute an openssl command in macos termninal `openssl smime...`

`smime` is called a subcommand. OpenSSL has lots of them:

- `enc`
- `dec`
- `s_client`
- `s_server`
- `smime`
- etc

---

> I would like to know the C functions associated with console commands. In particular this one up.

The source code for the subcommands are located in the [`<openssl src>/apps`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/apps) directory. For the `smime` command see [`smime.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/smime.c).

Comment: I'd been reading this file and cannot make things work.
Thanks for your help @jww.

Comment: @Carlos - I'm probably splitting hairs, but *"... I cannot make things work"* was never part of your question. In fact, you never stated what you tried or how things did not work. I cited your questions I answered. If you have another question, then you should ask a new question

Comment: Thanks pal! Yeahh you're right I don't want to abuse.

Comment: I don't mean to bother, you but if you don't mind to tell me, where can I find load_cert and load_key functions?

Comment: @CarlosMariaCaraccia - `load_cert` is in `apps/apps.c`. Most of the common functions used in subcommands are in `apps.{h|c}`. `$ grep -IR 'load_cert(' | grep X509` is also your friend.

Comment: As you asked I'd asked another question. I don't mean to bother you. @jww

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the parameters, but this is the gist of it for `SMIME` signing.. For example, I use this for Apple-Wallet signing (removed error checking to make it simpler):

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>



int main()
{
    //Setup OpenSSL..
    SSL_library_init();
    OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf();
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    //Load P12..
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_file("p12", "rb");
    PKCS12* p12 = d2i_PKCS12_bio(bio, nullptr);
    BIO_free_all(bio);

    EVP_PKEY* pkey = nullptr;
    X509* certificate = nullptr;
    PKCS12_parse(p12, "password", &pkey, &certificate, nullptr);
    PKCS12_free(p12);

    //Load certificate..
    bio = BIO_new_file("pem", "rb");
    X509* cert2 = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    EVP_PKEY* pkey2 = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    BIO_free_all(bio);


    //Load digest..
    const EVP_MD* md = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha1");

    //Load file to sign..
    bio = BIO_new_file("fileToSign", "rb");

    //Sign the binary..
    PKCS7* pkcs7 = PKCS7_sign(cert2, pkey2, nullptr, bio, PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_STREAM);
    PKCS7_sign_add_signer(pkcs7, certificate, pkey, md, PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_STREAM);
    PKCS7_add_certificate(pkcs7, cert2);
    PKCS7_final(pkcs7, bio, PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_STREAM);
    BIO_free_all(bio);

    //Cleanup..
    X509_free(cert2);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey2);
    X509_free(certificate);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

    //Save the signature to a file..
    bio = BIO_new_file("Signature", "rb");
    i2d_PKCS7_bio(bio, pkcs7);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    PKCS7_free(pkcs7);

    //Cleanup OpenSSL
    EVP_cleanup();
    CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
    return 0;
}
```

It will read your PrivateKey (p12 format), your signer certificate, the file to be signed, sign it, and output in DER format. You can modify it to output in PEM format and remove the `PKCS7_DETACH` flag for "-nodetach".

This one signs using the sha1 digest (Apple required it).. You can change the digest if needed.

Comment: I'm struggling I cannot load the private key. It is in pkcs10 format. So, the result is a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Brandon, but I cannot make things work.

Comment: @CarlosMariaCaraccia; To read PKCS10 aka CSR (Certificate Signing Request), you can use: `X509_REQ *PEM_read_bio_X509_REQ(BIO *bp, X509_REQ **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u)` or just convert the CSR to P12.

Comment: I cannot make things work with this command. I obtain a partial result. I have posted another question, the flags are confusing me a lot. Do you know any book which I can read from? Or anyway I can make this work? @Brandon Thanks for your help.