# From within MAMP: The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1

Tags: php, macos, openssl, mamp, osx-yosemite

> Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with
>   Composer. If you encounter issues, try to change the following:
>
> The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or
>   TLSv1.1. If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or
>   above.

I see similar questions like this were asked before, but not about this issue from within MAMP. I get this after a fresh install of MAMP on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

also, echo $PATH

> chendeMacBook-Air:MAMP doudou$ echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/bin:/Users/doudou/progs:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/DevDesktop/drush

Already put more than an hour on this. Any help appreciate,
Thanks.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say for `SSL Version`? And which version of MAMP did you install?

Comment: may get beter results on a mac\server site

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Comment: @jww your comment is exactly where my evening went, down the toilet. :P In my case, it's not an issue with OpenSSL install on my mac, it's an issue with something in MAMP. All those posts were about installing OpenSSL on an OS who's creators prefer you'd just buy a new machine instead of upgrading any software on it. Anyway, nothing todo with me, it's an issue from within MAMP only. I should remember to always look at the big picture.

Comment: @rndus2r yeah, OpenSSL version 1.0.2j, so I don't have a problem and it's just a silly warning I should ignore. Or waste a couple of hours, no biggie .. ouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpinfo() says OpenSSL version is 1.0.2j, not 0.9.8zc. Don't know where that warning is coming from. That comes up after installing composer in MAMP. I don't understand how it's looking up OpenSSL version installed on my machine. Anyway, I think it's good to leave this here to help out others that might face the same problem. The ton of other threads on upgrading OpenSSL in MAMP isn't relevant. At least I hope I'm right about this so I don't waste another 2 hours in the bushes.