# mac os upgrade openssl

Tags: c, macos, openssl, homebrew, nghttp2

My Mac OS system is: OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5.
And its openssl version is 0.9.8zg.
Now I want to install an nghttp2 tool, and it requires openssl>=1.0.1.
So I try brew update and brew install openssl.
After that I use command: `openssl version`,it shows:`OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017`.

But when I go to nghttp2 directory and run the `./configure`command,it still shows:

`configure: Requested 'openssl >= 1.0.1' but version of OpenSSL is 0.9.8zg`.

I am confused, why the latest version not used but still use the old one?

Comment: You'll need to tell the configure command where to find your Brew'd OpenSSL.  Try `./configure --help | less` (because the output is likely to be voluminous).

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.