# Mac install openssl , environment failed to found

Tags: node.js, macos, openssl

I've installed openssl.and when I enter openssl, the command line can recognize it .but My node configure can't find it.

see the pics below

[image]

I've tried to add path in .bash_profile

and try some tips from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129977/how-to-install-latest-version-of-openssl-mac-os-x-el-capitan)
but none of them works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed `openssl` using `brew` you may need to set `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`, from:

```
brew info openssl
```

> This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
>   because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries.

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
```

If you try to link you will get a warning something like this:

```
$ brew link --force openssl
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

What you could do is create a symlink so that the libraries could be found by the compiler:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl /usr/local/include
```

That should allow you to compile `node-v0.6.1`:

```
$ ./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc
Checking for gcc                         : ok
Checking for library dl                  : yes
Checking for openssl                     : yes
Checking for library util                : yes
Checking for library rt                  : not found
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : no
'configure' finished successfully (0.998s)
```

Comment: you save my day,3ks!