# Linking compiler to openssl for lcrypto library

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, openssl, symlink

After upgrading to Ventura, I just can't figure out how to fix this error:

```
cc -O3 -flto -ggdb -I ccan/ -Wall  -O3 -flto  ccan/tools/configurator/configurator.c  -lcrypto -o ccan/tools/configurator/configurator
ld: library not found for -lcrypto
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ccan/tools/configurator/configurator] Error 1
```

I've cloned and am trying to build the code from bitcoin-iterate if that helps at all.

https://github.com/rustyrussell/bitcoin-iterate

I know this question's been asked many times and I have spent quite a bit of time trying absolutely everything I could find online. I tried everything from this link: [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129977/how-to-install-latest-version-of-openssl-mac-os-x-el-capitan)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling openssl multiple times. When I run openssl version -a it gives me this:

```
OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022)
built on: Tue Nov  1 14:14:36 2022 UTC
platform: darwin64-arm64-cc
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: clang -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3"
ENGINESDIR: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.7/lib/engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.7/lib/ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: OPENSSL_armcap=0x7d
```

When I go into homebrew it shows openssl@1.1 still there. If I try and remove it completely I get a warning saying that other things are dependent on it, like python3.9. Do I have two versions of OpenSSL? Would this affect the link? Is it something in the Makefile of the code? Just can't seem to figure it out, would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

We're good to go. I installed OpenSSL directly from source instead of using Homebrew.